# how to get text from all the child nodes in AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice, accessibility, accessibility-api

I'm trying to read the text from all the child nodes of an AccessiblityNodeInfo.

I tried getting `AccessiblityNodeInfo.getParent()` and `AccessibilityNodeInfo.getChildCount()`

```
for(int i=0; i<accessibilityNodeInfo.getChildCount();i++){
accessibilityNodeInfo.getChild(i).getText();
}
```

Accessed the child nodes as mentioned above to get the text from the child nodes. but it is not providing the all the text on the screen.

Can anyone suggest me what to do get the text?

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<CharSequence> getAllChildNodeText(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat infoCompat) {
    List<CharSequence> contents = new ArrayList<>();
    if (infoCompat == null)
        return contents;
    if (infoCompat.getContentDescription() != null) {
        contents.add(infoCompat.getContentDescription().toString().isEmpty() ? "unlabelled" : infoCompat.getContentDescription());
    } else if (infoCompat.getText() != null) {
        contents.add(infoCompat.getText().toString().isEmpty() ? "unlabelled" : infoCompat.getText());
    } else {
        getTextInChildren(infoCompat, contents);
    }
    if (infoCompat.isClickable()) {
        if (infoCompat.getClassName().toString().contains(Button.class.getSimpleName())) {
            if (contents.size() == 0) {
                contents.add("Unlabelled button");
            } else {
                contents.add("button");
            }
        }
        contents.add("Double tap to activate");
    }
    return contents;
}


private void getTextInChildren(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat nodeInfoCompat, List<CharSequence> contents) {
    if (nodeInfoCompat == null)
        return;
    if (!nodeInfoCompat.isScrollable()) {
        if (nodeInfoCompat.getContentDescription() != null) {
            contents.add(nodeInfoCompat.getContentDescription());
        } else if (nodeInfoCompat.getText() != null) {
            contents.add(nodeInfoCompat.getText());
        }
        if (nodeInfoCompat.getChildCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeInfoCompat.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (nodeInfoCompat.getChild(i) != null) {
                    getTextInChildren(nodeInfoCompat.getChild(i), contents);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to do it:

in MyAccessibilityService class in onServiceConnected:

```
 @Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes =
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED |
                    AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED |
                    AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;

    this.setServiceInfo(info);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

then in onAccessibilityEvent i write this :

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {



    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    if (source == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (count(source.getChildCount()) != null) {
            String words = "";
            getChild(source);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

the main function do it is getChild():

```
    private void getChild(AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo1;
    int c = accessibilityNodeInfo.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        accessibilityNodeInfo1 = accessibilityNodeInfo.getChild(i);
        getChild(accessibilityNodeInfo1);
        if (accessibilityNodeInfo1.getText() != null) {
            words += accessibilityNodeInfo1.getText() + " ";
            Log.d("MYTAG", "getText: " + accessibilityNodeInfo1.getText());
            Log.d("MYTAG", "getChild: --------------------------------------------------");

        }
    }
}
```

Now you have text from all the child nodes in AccessibilityNodeInfo

Comment: It would be more helpful if you not only explained the "how", but the "why", too. "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man how to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."